# Jetty JNDI Jumpstart NamingException unknown JNDI name prefix 'org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext test-jndi

Tags: java, jetty, jndi, tapestry, openejb

Is there a way to solve this? I am also new to both tapestry, jetty, and openejb. I am having out of ideas =(

Configuration: Jetty 6.1.26 + OpenEJB 4.5.1 running Jumpstart for Tapestry 6.8

All compiles well, runs Ant collapser successfully, and deployed well. Jetty and OpenEJB are prestine from the binary zip. Just that OpenEjb have hsqldb-2.8 rather than hsqldb-2.9 which is instructed from the tapestry-jumpstart install manual.

But at some point when running in Eclipse Juno or IntelliJ IDEA (doesnt matter) I get this following log:

```
INFO - Deployed Application(path=E:\Workspace\IdeaProjects\tapestry\jumpstart-6.8.0\classpath.ear)
WARN [main] (Slf4jLog.java:76) - Config error at <New id="wiggle" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.EnvEntry"><Arg><Ref id="wac"/></Arg><Arg>wiggle</Arg><Arg type="java.lang.Double">100</Arg><Arg type="boolean">true</Arg></New>
WARN [main] (Slf4jLog.java:89) - EXCEPTION 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unknown JNDI name prefix 'org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@40ad55ac{_test-jndi,c:'
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:130)
...
WARN [main] (Slf4jLog.java:76) - ContextDeployer$Scanner failed on 'C:\Server\jetty-6.1.26\contexts\test-jndi.xml
INFO [main] (Slf4jLog.java:67) - NO JSP Support for /jumpstart, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO [main] (RegistryBuilder.java:129) - Adding module definition for class org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong with this? and what should I do?

Thanks much.

Comment: At what point did you get the error log?

Comment: if you are new to jetty, I would not start on a version that is over 150 releases old

Comment: Hi jesse, yes thats true, but I am just starting to learn tapestry with openejb, and so I found jumpstart as a template to start learning since its well integrated. However, I found its tutorial installation confusing.

Comment: Hi tsippert, after compling, and making the run-configuration in Eclipse, and then running the run configuration.